# How to generate ints with varying signs?

Tags: python, generator

I want to generate such numbers: `1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...`

But I don't know how to do it in Python.

```
def genNumbers():
    gi = genInt()
    while True:
        yield gi.next()

def genInt():
    i = 0
    while True: 
        i+=1
        yield i

gennr = genNumbers()
print gennr.next(), gennr.next(), gennr.next()
```

I wrote another generator that generates the numbers. The actual generator `genNumbers()` should change the signs of each number but I don't see a way to print every int in its signed state before going to the next int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def genInt():
    i = 0
    while True: 
        i+=1
        yield i
        yield -i

gennr = genInt()
```

Comment: Sometimes, Python is so ridiculously intuitive :)

Comment: Not to nitpick but Saphire said 'varying' whereas this is 'alternating'.  Clearly, they meant alternating as this is the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two generators to do this

```
def gen_numbers(n = 10):
    for current_number in xrange(1, n + 1):
        yield current_number
        yield -current_number

print list(gen_numbers())
```

If you want to do it your way, with two generators, simply change the `genNumbers` to remember the currently generated number and then yield that twice, once with the same sign and the next time with the sign inverted, like this

```
while True:
    current_number = next(gi)
    yield current_number
    yield -current_number
```

There is an elegant way to do this, with the `itertools`, like this

```
from itertools import izip, count

def gen_numbers():
    for numbers in izip(count(1), count(-1, -1)):
        for current_number in numbers:
            yield current_number

g = gen_numbers()
print next(g), next(g), next(g), next(g)
```

**Output**

```
1 -1 2 -2
```

**Note:** Be carefeul when using infinite iterables, with `zip`. `zip` will try to iterate the iterable till the end or `StopIteration` is raised. If you use that with infinte iterables, your program will not return control to you. So, remember to use `izip`, like I have shown in the answer.

Comment: Prefer `next(gi)` over `gi.next()`, former will work in both Python 2 & 3.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks man :) I didn't know that `.next` has been removed. Hitting the docs now.

Comment: Not removed, but they renamed it to `__next__` in Python3.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way seems to be:

```
import itertools

def gen_sequence():
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield i
        yield -i
```